# Bash Script rm command not running after tar command

Tags: bash, backup, tar, linux-mint, rm

Thanks for taking the time to read my post.

I wrote a small bash script to back up my home partition. It backs up correctly, but after it archives everything I want it to delete the old archives and it doesn't.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# config
src="/home"
trgt="/media/atlas/Backup/home.daily"
owd=$PWD
# abort if any of the commands fail
set -e

cd $trgt

todays=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d') # nicely sortable names for backups
last=$(ls -r | head -1)
to_delete=$(ls -r | tail -n +3) # will keep the last backup

tar -cvpzf ${todays}.tar.gz --exclude-from="/var/scripts/exclude.txt" --one-file-system /home > /var/log/backup/home.daily.${todays} 2>&1

# now we're safe to remove the old one(s)
rm -f $to_delete
```

The funny thing, is if I comment out that tar command, then rm -f $to_delete works like it should.

Could anyone shed some light on this? It looks like tar is blocking any other commands, but it perplexes me because I thought that these would be executed sequentially.

For background, the /media/atlas/ mount is mounted over Samba.

Comment: You have `set -e`, which will abort the script if any command fails.  So the `tar` command is probably failing, or at least returning a non-zero exit code.  Also try replacing your first line with `#!/bin/bash -x` to make bash print out each command before running it.

Comment: Before investigating any further, I would suggest that you wrap your variables in quotes. For example, `"${todays}.tar.gz"`. This will protect you against a whole class of problems related to [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting). As @dg99 has rightly pointed out, `set -x` is also useful when debugging.

Comment: Did you check the `/var/log/backup/home.daily.${todays}` log file contain any error strings from tar command

Comment: I didn't see any errors from the tar command (in the log), but I vaguely remember seeing something before... I commented out the "set -e" for now and am trying it again. Thanks for the help, I'll comment back when it finishes.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, if you are looking to debug the behaviour, perhaps it's worth running the script on a smaller directory (or at least a local one) :)

Comment: No you're right, haha I have been but I just posted the script as is. Thanks ;)